# Is there a way to batch distort images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, transform, batch-processing

In photoshop elements (or any other program really), is there a way to batch "distort" a bunch of images?

Lets say I have multiple images (all 500 by 500 pixels) and I want to distort them all to a certain shape,....is there a way to do that?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Photoshop has a batch functionality: you use the panel "actions". You "record" the steps you do on one image, and you can then run that action on as many images you like.

See the little record button at the bottom of the panel, that is how you record:

[image]

If you feel like getting very nerdy, you can look into ImageMagick, who is an incredibly powerful batch-tool. But maybe a little on the geeky side..

Comment: :) hope it works for you.

Comment: Totally not geeky! Super normal and totally regular to have tried that

Answer (score 1):

Once you set up the Action in Photoshop, batch processing runs from Bridge.

- Select all the images to process.
- Choose `Tools > Photoshop > Batch...`
- Fill in the details, with the Action you want to run.
- In the dialog, select your destination (probably a separate folder).
- Let it roll.

If you have a few hundred images to process this way, this will be a good time to take a break, look out the window and enjoy the fact that you're not doing them by hand.